# Unable to find the minimum number of vertical and horizontal cuts due to the following error

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I am writing a code to find the minimum number of horizontal and vertical cuts to form a square. I am generating 'cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object' error, does this have anything to do with the functools package? If not, what changes can I make otherwise?

```
import functools

@functools.lru_cache
def get_C(height, width):
    if height == width:
        return("",0)
    cold = height*width
    for tryleftlen in range(1, width//2+1):
        leftcuts, leftminimum = get_C(height, tryleftlen)
        rightcuts, rightminimum = get_C(height, width-tryleftlen)
        ctry = 1+leftminimum +rightminimum
        if ctry < cold:
            minimumcut = 'V{0}x{1} --> {0}x{2} {0}x{3}\n'.format(height,width,tryleftlen,width-tryleftlen)
            minimumcut += leftcuts + rightcuts
            cold = ctry
        for trybotlength in range(1, height//2+1):
            topcuts, topminimum = get_C(height-trybotlength, width)
            botcuts, botminimum = get_C(trybotlength, width)
            ctry = 1+ botminimum + topminimum
            if ctry < cold:
                minimumcut = 'H{0}x{1}-->{2}x{1} {3}x{1}\n'.format(height,width,trybotlength.height-trybotlength)
                minimumcut += botcuts + topcuts
                cold = ctry 
        return (minimumcut, cold)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    C = get_C(6,7)
    C = get_C(12,13)
    print(C[0])
```

Comment: Line `return (minimumcut, cold)` is very suspiciously indented. I assume it should be outside of loop `for tryleftlen in range(1, width//2+1):`, but currently it is inside.

Comment: BTW, I don't really understand what you mean by "the minimum number of horizontal and vertical cuts to form a square". Could you explain in a bit more detail?

Comment: we need to find the minimum number of horizontal and vertical cuts for a rectangle with two dimensions to form a square.

Comment: I still have no idea what you mean by that. What is it that you call a "cut"? Can you show a drawing of a rectangle and how you'd transform it into a square? With what I imagine the word "cut" to mean, we'd need only one cut to transform a non-square rectangle into a square: just truncate out a bit so that the rectangle (W, L) is cut into two bits (W, W) and (W, L-W). The first bit (W, W) will be square.

Answer (score 0):

oops, it was a small syntax error and nothing to do with import functools.
at this line:

```
 minimumcut = 'H {0}x{1} --> {2}x{1} {3}x{1}\n'.format(height,width,trybotlength,height-trybotlength)
```

Thank you.

Comment: this might not have happened if you [put a blank after most every comma](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: yes, will follow it in future, thank you :)